# Confusion matrix CrossTable Include NA to get Accuracy

Tags: r, statistics

I am very new to R and I want to  examine a Confusion table statistics including NAs. 
This is some sample data:

```
 #Sample data: predicted score and reference/actual score
 predtest <- c(1,1,1,3,NA,2,2,NA,1,2,3,3,3,NA,2)
 reftest <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5))
```

CrossTable presents NA; but does not give me overall Accuracy:

```
  CrossTable(predtest, reftest,
       prop.t=TRUE,
       missing.include=TRUE,
       format=c("SAS", "SPSS"), dnn = c("Prediction", "Actual"))
```

Confusion presents Accuracy; but does not include NAs(!):

```
 confusionMatrix(predtest, reftest)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this it would be much appreciated. 
Thank you!